# Issues accessing command prompt from python script

Tags: python, cmd

I am trying to open twitch streams in VLC using python and livestreamer. When I open up a normal command prompt and type in:

```
livestreamer twitch.tv/*stream_here* best
```

It works completely fine.  However, when I add:

```
os.system('livestreamer twitch.tv/%s best' %(streamName))
```

to my python script, the command prompt that is opened by the python script says that livestreamer is not recognized as an internal or external command.  Livestreamer has definitely been added to my path, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Check your path or use the full path to `livestreamer`.

Comment: you can use `which livestreamer` command to check path

Comment: @LutzHorn, I have checked the path, and the path to the livestreamer executable is there.

Comment: Python seems to not know the path. Put the complete path into your `os.system` call.